# How to show qTip ballon unless you click the "X" button

Tags: jquery, cookies, qtip2, jquery-cookie

I have the next code

```
    if ($.cookie('show-tooltip') != "false") {
        $('#logo')
            .qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'some text', 
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        button: true
                    }
                },
                show: {
    event: false,
    ready: true
},
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom left', 
                    at: 'top left', 
                       adjust: {
                         x: 80,
                         y: 30
                        }
                        },
        events: {
            hide: function() {
                $.cookie('show-tooltip', false);
                console.log( $.cookie('show-tooltip') )
            }
        },       
                style: {
                    classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-dark'
                }
            });

}
}); ​
```

I have some issues:

1.If I pass the click arrow in front of the logo, the qTip balloon (want it to stay open)
    closes.

2.Can't make it closing when the X (close button) is clicked only: I
    want to make it re-open each time the page is refreshed, unless you
    have clicked the X button before.

Can somebody guide me please ?

Comment: @rajeshkakawat don't you think that in order to do the above code, I used those instructions ? I find your comment unconstructive and spam